# Spring boot application can't start in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-3

I trie to make a Spring-boot application exposing simple REST web service. I follow getting started instruction. I developping with an Eclipse Oxygen IDE.

When I try to launch my application like a Java Application I get an error : Application failed to start with classpath.

This is my parametrage :

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fr.omb</groupId>
    <artifactId>omb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the main launcher class

```
/**
 * 
 */
package fr.omb;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * @author omb
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("fr.omb")
public class MainLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MainLauncher.class, args);
    }

}
```

The database configuration

```
---

spring: profile: dev 
   jpa:

      hibernate:
         ddl-auto: create-drop 
      datasource:
         platform: postgresql
         url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/omb
         username: xxxxxx
         password: xxxxxx
         driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver

---
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show the stack trace? \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the Spring Eclipse Plugin for Oxygen installed?  You need to launch as a Spring (or Spring-Boot) application, not Java application.

[image: Spring-Boot Debug launch Configuration]